# Using group by for attributes which will not be selected

Tags: sql

Let's suppose that I have the following table:

```
employee (id, name, surname, salary);
```

The question is: Can I group the selection with attributes which don't appear in the select clause?

For example:

```
select count (*)
from employee
where salary > 40000
group by id
```

I know that in this case the `group by` clause is useless, but it just an example. Is this correct?

Comment: Just run the query and see if it error's or not. To my knowledge it will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implementation dependent. For example, Oracle requires that the columns named in the 'group by' clause appear in the select statement. Others, including MySql, for example, do not.

Answer (score 0):

for what the professor told us, the attributes written in the group by clause should be added to the select clause automatically. Sorry for the late answer but I was looking for something else and I saw this.