# Why does group by statement do not return correct rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm going through a tutorial and I can't understand why my query is not working.

I have 2 tables :

`authors`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | JK Rowling |
| 2 | Stephen King |
| 3 | Agatha Christie |
| 4 | Dr Seuss |

`books`

| id | title | author_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chamber of Secrets | 1 |
| 2 | Prizoner of Azkaban | 1 |
| 3 | The Dark Tower | 2 |
| 4 | Murder at the Links | 3 |
| 5 | Affait at Styles | 3 |
| 6 | Cat in the hat | 4 |

The task was to write a query that would print an author's name and the number of books they have authored.

My solution was this one:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)   
FROM books
JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id
GROUP BY author_id
```

However, in the result there is no **name** row.  I know that the correct solution is to `GROUP BY name`, however I can't understand why I can't group by `author_id`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use a dummy aggregate like `min(name)`. All rows in a group will have the same name but an aggregate function is necessary to pull out a single value.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969840/using-group-by-for-attributes-which-will-not-be-selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should write your query with qualified column references so it is easier to follow:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*)   
FROM books b JOIN
     authors a
     ON b.author_id = a.id
GROUP BY b.author_id;
```

Why doesn't this work?  Clearly the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` columns are different!  They are not even from the same table.

The following *might* work:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*)   
FROM books b JOIN
     authors a
     ON b.author_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

This would work if `authors.id` is declared to be the primary key or `unique` -- which is quite likely.  This works because of a capability called *functional dependence*, which alls for any column to be referenced when a unique or primary key is in a `GROUP BY` key.

However, if there is no such explicit declaration, then you need `a.name` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Noob . . . It seems to explain the issue in your question.  I'm surprised you didn't accept it.

Comment: ohhh, that was a misclick .

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, any column not given a aggregate function needs to be present in the group by statement.

In your case

```
select name, ..
```

requires

```
group by name, ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: `count(*)` is totally reasonable.  There is absolutely not reason to suggest not using it.